# Creating dynamic content and form with angular directive based on object\json

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, json, forms

I'm struggling with creating dynamic form and structure and cannot find a solution.

Details: The back-end sends me the services object(or json) that I should use to create a dynamic structure with services name inside and so on. The object also contains the information to create the form connected to the service (look at the image attached).
Also, when you select a service (clicking the left square button) the form should appear immediately, but you should also be able to change it dinamycally if you click the circular button (only if the relative service left button is enabled)
When the left button is deflag then the data of that service should whipe out to blank the form if reopened.

I hope someone could help me with this

I just cannot find a way to connect all logics

```
  var services = [ {
                    "id" : "001",
                    "name" : "Serv1",
                    "fields" : []
                }, {
                    "id" : "002",
                    "name" : "Serv2",
                    "fields" : []
                }, {
                    "id" : "003",
                    "name" : "Serv3",
                    "fields" : [ {
                        "type" : "text",
                        "name" : "operation",
                        "label" : "Operation",
                        "required" : false,
                        "data" : ""
                    }, {
                        "type" : "text",
                        "name" : "note",
                        "label" : "Note",
                        "required" : false,
                        "data" : ""
                    }, {
                        "type" : "select",
                        "name" : "profile",
                        "label" : "Profile",
                        "options" : [ {
                            "name" : "000 - None",
                            "value" : "000"
                        }, {
                            "name" : "001 - Profile 1",
                            "value" : "001"
                        }, {
                            "name" : "002 - Profile 2",
                            "value" : "002"
                        } ],
                        "required" : false,
                        "data" : ""
                    } ]
                }, {
                    "id" : "004",
                    "name" : "Serv4",
                    "fields" : [ {
                        "type" : "checkbox",
                        "name" : "develop",
                        "label" : "Develop possibility",
                        "required" : false,
                        "data" : false
                    }, {
                        "type" : "checkbox",
                        "name" : "acceptance",
                        "label" : "Accept",
                        "required" : false,
                        "data" : false
                    } ]
                } ];
```

dynamicForm.html

```
[<div ng-controller="??"  directive="???">
    <md-card class="row" style="margin-bottom:20px;margin-left:0px;position:relative;max-width:650px;">
        <md-toolbar class="md-toolbar-tools" style="background-color:rgb(138, 180, 213);margin-bottom:10px;">{{SERVICE Name}}</md-toolbar>
        <form name="myForm" class="form-horizontal" role="form" ng-submit="submitForm()" layout="row" layout-wrap style="padding-left: 40px;">
            <div ng-repeat="field in fields" flex=33>    
                <ng-form name="form">


                    <!-- TEXT FIELDS -->
                    <div ng-if="field.type=='text'">
                        <md-input-container>
                            <label>{{field.label}}</label>
                            <input type="{{ field.type }}" dynamic-name="field.name" id="{{field.name}}" data-ng-model="field.data"/>
                        </md-input-container>    
                    </div>


                    <!-- EMAIL FIELDS -->
                    <div ng-if="field.type=='email'">
                        <md-input-container>
                            <label>{{field.label}}</label>
                            <input type="{{ field.type }}" dynamic-name="field.name" data-ng-model="field.data" />
                            <span data-ng-show=" {{'form.'+field.name+'.$dirty && form.'+field.name+'.$error.required'}}">Inserire mail!</span>
                            <span data-ng-show=" {{'form.'+field.name+'.$dirty && form.'+field.name+'.$error.email'}}">Non &egrave; una mail valida</span>
                        </md-input-container>
                    </div>


                    <!-- PASSWORD FIELDS -->
                    <div ng-if="field.type=='password'">
                        <md-input-container>
                            <label>{{field.label}}</label>
                            <input type="{{ field.type }}" dynamic-name="field.name" data-ng-model="field.data" ng-minlength={{field.min}} ng-maxlength={{field.max}} />
                            <span data-ng-show=" {{'form.'+field.name+'.$dirty && form.'+field.name+'.$error.required'}}">Required!</span>
                            <span data-ng-show=" {{'!form.'+field.name+'.required && (form.'+field.name+'.$error.minlength || form.'+field.name+'.$error.maxlength)' }}">Passwords must be between 8 and 20 characters.</span>
                        </md-input-container>
                    </div>


                    <!-- SELECT FIELDS -->
                    <div ng-if="field.type=='select'">
                        <md-input-container>
                            <label>{{field.label}}</label>
                            <md-select dynamic-name="field.name" data-ng-model="field.data">
                                <md-option ng-repeat="option in field.options" ng-value="option.value">{{option.name}}</md-option>
                            </md-select> 
                        </md-input-container>
                    </div>      

                     <!-- DATE FIELDS -->
                    <div ng-if="field.type=='date'">
                        <md-input-container>
                            <label>{{field.label}}</label>
                            <md-datepicker dynamic-name="field.name" data-ng-model="field.data" md-min-date="field.min" md-max-date="field.max"></md-datepicker>
                        </md-input-container>
                    </div> 

                    <!-- RADIO FIELDS -->
                    <div ng-if="field.type=='radio'">
                        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">{{field.label}}</label>
                        <div class="checkbox" ng-repeat="option in field.options" >
                            <label>                
                                <input type="radio" data-ng-model="field.data"  name="taskGroup"  id="{{option.name}}" value="{{option.id}}">{{option.name}}
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <!-- CHECKBOX FIELDS -->
                    <div ng-if="field.type=='checkbox'">
                        <md-input-container>
                            <md-checkbox dynamic-name="field.name" data-ng-model="field.data" name="taskGroup" id="{{option.name}}" value="{{option.id}}">
                                {{field.label}}
                            </md-checkbox>
                        <md-input-container>
                   </div>
                </ng-form>
            </div>
        </form>
    </md-card>
</div>]
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Xk2s.png

Answer (score 0):

I think *formly* can give what you need, see their example http://angular-formly.com/#/example/intro/introduction. So, in your example you just need to modify *fields* property to match *formly* structure and format